# The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I can't get `TryGetValue` to work for some reason.

```
Dictionary<String,String> testdict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
String teststr = "test";
if(testdict.TryGetValue(teststr,out value))
{
    //Ladida
}
```

Error received:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.TryGetValue(string, out string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like *value* is not a variable of type string.  We can't see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this line after creating the dictionary:

```
String value = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that `value` isn't properly typed to `string`.  This is the only reason that you would get that particular error.  You need to change the type of value to `string` or declare a new variable of type `string` to use in `TryGetValue`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dictionary<String,String> testdict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
string theValueYouAreTryingFor = "test";
string theValueYourGetting;
if(testdict.TryGetValue(theValueYouAreTryingFor,out theValueYourGetting))
{
    //If the value is in the Dictionary
}
```